# Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] when implementing an elapsed time calculator

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am getting this error in the browser console in my code for an elapsed time calculator:

```
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig]
```

I calculate the elapsed time from the current time when the app starts.

Here is my html:

```
<div ng-app="time">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl2">
    Elapsed time: <span my-current-time="[date,format]"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
function Ctrl2($scope) {
  $scope.date = new Date();
  $scope.format = 'M/d/yy h:mm:ss a';
}

angular.module('time', [])
  // Register the 'myCurrentTime' directive factory method.
  // We inject $timeout and dateFilter service since the factory method is DI.
  .directive('myCurrentTime', function($timeout, dateFilter) {
    // return the directive link function. (compile function not needed)
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var format,  // date format
          timeoutId; // timeoutId, so that we can cancel the time updates
      var since;   

      // used to update the UI
      function updateTime() {
        element.text(dateFilter(since, format));
        element.text( (((new Date()).getTime() - since.getTime())/(1000*60)%60) + " minutes, since " + dateFilter(since, format));  
      }

      // watch the expression, and update the UI on change.
      //scope.$watch(attrs.myCurrentTime, function(value) {
       // format = value;
       // updateTime();
      //});

      scope.$watch(attrs.myCurrentTime, function(value) {
          since = value[0];
          format = value[1];
          updateTime();
      });

      // schedule update in one second
      function updateLater() {
        // save the timeoutId for canceling
        timeoutId = $timeout(function() {
          updateTime(); // update DOM
          updateLater(); // schedule another update
        }, 1000);
      }

      // listen on DOM destroy (removal) event, and cancel the next UI update
      // to prevent updating time ofter the DOM element was removed.
      element.bind('$destroy', function() {
        $timeout.cancel(timeoutId);
      });

      updateLater(); // kick off the UI update process.
    }
  });
```

Please Help, I have also made the fiddle to have a look at the code

http://jsfiddle.net/sojharo/9FnU2/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I've located the issue. I have an assumption that angular creates new arrays each evaluation so it always fires watcher

`function Ctrl2($scope) {
      $scope.date = new Date();
      $scope.format = 'M/d/yy h:mm:ss a';
      $scope.options = [$scope.date, $scope.format]; //<--line added
}`

`<div ng-app="time">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl2">
        Elapsed time: <span my-current-time="options"></span> //<-- binding change.
    </div>
</div>`

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9FnU2/7/)

**ADDED**

Also not sure that you really need this watch functionality. Bear in mind that watch works on whole array in your case not inner elements. You can extract value this `scope.$eval(attrs.myCurrentTime)`.

Comment: Does it mean when it fires watcher next time, it does not get the array in the value of directive in span? it is working by the way, thanks :)

Comment: It will fire if you replace options variable