# how to use one ng-controller within another ng-app and controller in angular.js

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angular.js and want to use one `ng-controller` within another `ng-app` and `ng-controller` like this so that I will be able to use the code before I used on the other pages as well.
Please help me out and correct me if I am wrong anywhere.

```
<div id="divFriendList" class="container" ng-app="friendModule" ng-controller="friendController">
    <div id="module2" ng-app="cardsModule" ng-controller="CardsController">
        <div ng-repeat="card in cards></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am rather new as well, but I believe a way to do this would be to declare a dependency in your module.  For example, `angular.module('friendModule', ['cardsModule']);`.  Such an example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16113890/using-a-child-controller-from-another-module).  For more about modules and a tutorial on angular you can visit [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_modules.asp).

As for your code, you're missing the closing quotation in `<div ng-repeat="card in cards>`.  Further, you are asking ng-repeat to iterate each `card` in `cards`, but you have not defined what `cards` is.  Therefore, you'll want to change

`<div id="module2" ng-app="cardsModule" ng-controller="CardsController">`

to

`<div id="module2" ng-app="cardsModule" ng-controller="CardsController as cards">`.

Additionally, you will not get any information displayed if you don't ask for an output such as {{card}}.  I would also consider declaring your ng-apps before hand and not when they're needed - but I'm unsure as to the efficiency of this.

What I would update as:

```
 <div id="divFriendList" class="container" ng-app="friendModule" ng-controller="friendController">
     <div id="module2" ng-app="cardsModule" ng-controller="CardsController as cards">
         <div ng-repeat="card in cards">{{ card }}</div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks It worked fine for me but I am getting this error  Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] when I click on any link.Please help me out to resolve that

Comment: As I said, I'm a newbie as well so I'm unsure what it could be, but these might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26723927/angularjs-uncaught-error-rootscopeinfdig-10-digest-iterations-reached and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25103966/uncaught-error-rootscopeinfdig-in-browser-console-when-implementing-a-elaps